# Dataframe manipulation - capturing a change in value

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe as below, which shows a change in position, add 1 unit, subtract 1 unit or do nothing (0).

[image]

I'm looking to create a second dataframe with the net position, which is either long (1) or flat (0) - assuming a net short (-1) position is not possible.

So the logic is to start with 0, switch to 1 when the first +1 'change in position' occurs (any subsequent +1 is ignored), then only switch back to 0 when a -1 is seen.

Any thoughts on how to do this? The idea is to create df2 as per below

[image]

df.cumsum() would work if each +1 'change in position' were to count, but I only wish to capture 'long or flat' not the size of any accumulated long position.

Input data frame:

[image]

Output data frame:

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is probably just a loop over the dataframe

Comment: @Deb Easiest and the worst.

Comment: OP, please provide a copy paste of your data frame, it isn't possible working with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
df['CiP'].where(df['CiP'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill').diff(), 0).cumsum()
```

Explanation:

- The call to `replace` replaces `0` values by the preceding non-zero value.
- The call to `diff` then points to actual changes in position.
- The call to `where` ensures that values that do not really change are replaced by `0`.
- After this treatment, `cumsum` just works.

---

**Edit**: If you have multiple columns, then define a function as above and apply it.

```
def position(series):
    return series.where(series.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill').diff(), 0).cumsum()

df[list_of_columns].apply(position)
```

This could be slightly faster than explicitly looping over the columns.

Comment: Thanks. let's say there are a number of columns in the dataframe, not just one.... how do I apply this across the entire dataframe, not just a single column?

Comment: You could iterate over the columns. I would guess you have many rows but few columns, so the cost of iterating should be low.

Comment: I have 136 columns and 2k rows... so a little more complex

Comment: So how would I iterate over several columns?

Comment: That's great, thanks. Only thing is... if I have a -1 first before a +1, then that the output will show a series of -1's. Is there a simple way to replace any -1 with a 0?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the new input and the desired output? You can edit your question.

Comment: Hm, so you want to replace the first `-1` with a `0`, right?

Comment: I wan't to replace any -1 with a 0 such that the series can only be flat (0) or long (1). Any -1 should be ignored and the value in the output frame stored as 0.

Comment: Now that's difficult without a loop... I'll think about it but I don't see an obvious answer.

Comment: Actually I would recommend that you ask a new question, with the new requirement, and include the dataframe copied as text (not as image). This way your question will attract more attention and more people are likely to help.