# Python data frame logic - capturing a conditional change in value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question is a follow up to the original [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800152/dataframe-manipulation-capturing-a-change-in-value).

I have a dataframe as below (df1), which shows a change in position, add 1 unit (1), subtract 1 unit or do nothing (0).

[image]

I'm looking to create a second dataframe, df2, with the net position - but rather than doing the cumsum(), which would in effect show the rolling total number of units long or short, i want to assume that a short (-1) position is not possible and therefore the only values to appear in df2 would be either long (1), flat(0) but NOT short (-1).

So the logic is to start flat (0), if a +1 appears in df1 then then change to +1, otherwise stay at 0.

If a -1 occurs only subtract it from the rolling series if the previous value of the series is 1, i.e data in df2 can only b 0 or 1.

[image]

The below code partially works, but I need to add in functionality to exclude short (-1) positions.

```
def position(series):
return series.where(series.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill').diff(), 0).cumsum()

df[list_of_columns].apply(position)
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this question two days ago?

Comment: Don't know if it warrants a new question or not, but OP is asking this because the previously provided solution doesn't fit the requirements.  The provided dataframes are slightly different